# String equal/contain none of them gets what I want

Tags: java

I have a string that can look somewhat like:

```
NCC_johjon (\users\johanjo\tomcattest\oysters\NCC_johjon, port 16001), utv_johjon (\users\johanjo\tomcattest\oysters\utv_johjon, port 16000)
```

and there could be like a lot of NCC_etskys, NCC_homyis and so on and I want to check if somewhere in the string there is an part that says "NCC_joh" already existing. I tried with like

```
if(oysters.contains("NCC_joh")){
        System.out.println("HEJ HEJ HEJ HALLÅ HALLÅ HALLÅ");
    }
```

but if there is an NCC_johjon in there it will go in the if case, but I only want to go in if exact that part exist not longer not shorter and .equal it needs to look like the whole String which is not what I want either. anyone got any idea? would be better if what I worked with were a list of Strings but I don't have that.
the oysterPaths is an Collection at first

```
Collection<TomcatResource> oysterPaths = TomcatResource.listCats(Paths.get(tomcatsPath));
```

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you want the condition to be true only if it matches the string exactly, but you don't want to look at all the string? How do you expect it to know the string matches exactly it it doesn't look at the whole string?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "exact that part exist not longer not shorter"? That string occurs twice within your string - which one to you want to trigger it? Should it trigger if it's in the middle of the path? If you could provide a [mcve] with various cases that you want to match and not match?

Comment: I believe he wants to match exactly `NCC_joh` and not something like `NCC_johjon`(which would be longer)

Comment: Just include the open bracket in the contains? `if (oysters.contains("NCC_joh (")) {`

Comment: exactly as @XtremeBaumer says i want it to be exactly for example NCC_joh. i will try Mr Spoon solution

Comment: @MrSpoon Thanks that helped me cause it will always be an ( after the string i check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
if (oysters.matches("(?s).*\\bNCC_joh\\b.*")) {
```

where

- `(?s)` = single line mode, DOT-ALL, so `.` will match a newline too.
- `.` = any char
- `.*` = zero or more occurrences of `.` (any char)
- `\b` = word boundary

`String.matches` does a match of the pattern over the *entire* string, hence the need for `.*` at begin and end.

(Word boundaries of course means, that between them a *word* has to be placed.)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49879388/2735286, but I would suggest to use the `find` method using this regular expression:

```
\bNCC_joh\b
```

Using the find method will simplify the regular expression and you will exclusively search for what is relevant.

Here is the corresponding method you can use:

```
public static boolean superExactMatch(String expression) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bNCC_joh\\b", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(expression);
    final boolean found = matcher.find();
    if(found) {
        // For debugging purposes to see where the match happened in the expression
        System.out.println(matcher.start() + " " + matcher.end());
    }
    return found;
}
```